# Replacing letters in words

Tags: c#, arrays, string

Hello I'm having a little trouble on this one aspect in my code. I have some strings and I have a array of chars. I'm trying to replace the last two letters of each string
with the characters in the char array until the last one.

My array of char is as follows:

```
char[] array = { 'v', 'x', 'f' };
```

My code so far:

```
char[] array = { 'v', 'x', 'f' };
        string newWord="";
        string apple="apple";
        string sam="sam";

        foreach(char c in array)
        {
            apple= apple.Substring(0, apple.Length - 2) +""; ///DON'T KNOW WHAT TO PUT HERE;
            sam= sam.Substring(0, sam.Length - 2)+""; ///DON'T KNOW WHAT TO PUT HERE;
            newWord = apple+Environment.NewLine+sam ;     
        }
```

The output should like like this:

```
appvx
sfm
```

Maybe I'm doing this wrong but I'm explicitly telling it in the substring to get rid of the last to letters in the word but if the array runs out won't it still delete the last two. For instance the word sam still needs to have m at the end of it since all the chars in the array have already been used like what the out but shows but replace a with f

Comment: That's not your real code, because it won't compile as it is now. Please [edit] your question and post your **actual** code; making up code as you go along in your question isn't an actual effort to solve the problem.

Comment: yes i know it wont compile because i'm missing semi-colons

Comment: I don't know C#, but seems like you should:  1> Use a loop that knows a count 2> Only operate on one string per loop ( you could put the strings into an array ) and as far as `sam` becoming `sfm`, my guess is that you need to set the `sam` pointer to something like '\0' before you write over it - see the answer from @JleruOHeP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
private static void something()
{
    List<char> tokens = new List<char>(new char[]{ 'v', 'x', 'f' });

    List<char[]> lArr = new List<char[]>();
    lArr.Add("apple".ToCharArray());
    lArr.Add("sam".ToCharArray());

    List<string> lStr = new List<string>();

    int cnt = 2;

    foreach (var token in tokens)
    {
        var aktArr = lArr.FirstOrDefault();
        if (aktArr == null)
            break;
        if (cnt == 0) 
        {
            cnt = 2;
            lStr.Add(new string(aktArr));
            lArr.RemoveAt(0);
            aktArr = lArr.FirstOrDefault();
            if (aktArr == null)
                break;
        }
        aktArr[aktArr.Length - cnt--] = token;
    }
    lStr.AddRange(lArr.Select(x => new string(x)));

    foreach (var item in lStr)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok so I actually have to split the words and put in them is a list of chars

Comment: just a different approach ... you don't "have to" ... you can perfectly do this without a single char array ...

Comment: oh ok thanks it make sense I'm not to good with LINQ but I understand now thank you so much for your help. It took me a while trying to figure out how i could do it without a list

Answer (score 1):

You can treat a string as an array of chars, so the result can be something like this (supposing that you have an array of words, not only 2 variables for them and a little helper to replace chars)

```
var words = new [] {"apple", "sam"};
var wordPos = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
  var wordLen = words[wordPos].Length;
  var letterPos = i % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 2;  
  words[wordPos] = words[wordPos].ReplaceAt(wordLen - letterPos, letter);
  if (letterPos == 1) wordPos++;
}

public static string ReplaceAt(this string input, int index, char newChar)
{
    if (input == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("input");
    }
    char[] chars = input.ToCharArray();
    chars[index] = newChar;
    return new string(chars);
}
```

Comment: god bless you sir thanks for the help I don't know why i didn't use a collection like everyone else

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this will do what you need:

```
        var charArray = new[] {'a', 'b', 'c'};
        var words = new List<string> {"apple", "sam"};
        var currentWord = 0;
        var currentChar = 0;
        var charsToReplace = 2;

        while (currentChar < charArray.Length && currentWord != words.Count)
        {
            var word = words[currentWord].ToCharArray();
            word[word.Length - charsToReplace] = charArray[currentChar];
            words[currentWord] = new string(word);

            charsToReplace--;
            currentChar++;
            if (charsToReplace == 0)
            {
                charsToReplace = 2;
                currentWord++;
            }
        }

        words.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion and help it seems everyone actually put the words in a list